# Wildfly 10 Final postgres driver ClassCastException

Tags: jdbc, postgresql-9.4, wildfly-10

eventually somebody can help me. Currently I have a really strange problem when starting **wildfly 10 Final** with a postgres driver but with the same setting **wildfly 10 CR4** will start up.

The exception I get is following:

```
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ031089: Failed to load datasource: org.postgresql.Driver
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getDataSource(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:650)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:311)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.postgresql.Driver cannot be cast to javax.sql.DataSource
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getDataSource(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:633)
    ... 7 more
```

The strange thing is, it works on wildfly 10 CR4 but not on the final version wildfly 10 Final. Any Idea?
For me it looks like a class loader problem but I'm not that an expert with wildfly to track it down.

my *modules/org/postgres/main/module.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="org.postgres">
  <resources>
    <resource-root path="postgresql-9.4.1208.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <dependencies>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
    <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
    <module name="javax.servlet.api" optional="true"/>
  </dependencies>
</module>
```

My driver definition in *standalone.xml*

```
<driver name="postgres" module="org.postgres">
    <xa-datasource-class>org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
    <datasource-class>org.postgresql.Driver</datasource-class>
</driver>
```

Java JDK is: jdk1.8.0_73

Would really appreciate any help to fix my problem.

Thx in advance

/david

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The class name implementing a DataSource is either:

```
org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource
```

or

```
org.postgresql.ds.PGPoolingDataSource
```

https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/ds-ds.html

I assume Wildfly will manage the connections, so you probably don't need the pooling DataSource, only the simple:
So it should be

```
<driver name="postgres" module="org.postgres">
    <xa-datasource-class>org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
    <datasource-class>org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource</datasource-class>
</driver>
```

Comment: A `ConnectionPoolDataSource` is not (or should not be) a `DataSource`. In the case of `PGConnectionPoolDataSource` it only implements `ConnectionPoolDataSource`. As far as I can tell WildFly expects a `DataSource` here.

Comment: Thank you so much both of you! Reading your response it sounds resonable ;) _datasource-class_ expects a data source.

Anyway, thx a lot!