# wildfly - installing postgres driver jar

Tags: jdbc, wildfly, wildfly-10

I am having difficulty installing the postgres driver.  I've tried a bunch of things:

1. https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Application+deployment

   a. tried "deploying" the JAR (both from CLI and admin console UI)
2. https://sites.google.com/site/jmdstips/jboss-wildfly/postgresql-on-wildfly---xa-datasource

   a. tried putting module definition in modules/org/postgresql ...

   b. tried putting module definition in modules/system/layers/base/org/postgresql

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="org.postgres">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar" />
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
        <module name="javax.servlet.api" optional="true"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

And:

```xml
<drivers>
    <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
        <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
    </driver>
        <driver name="postgresql" module="org.postgresql">
                <datasource-class>org.postgresql.Driver</datasource-class>
                <xa-datasource-class>org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
        </driver>
</drivers>
```

After all of that, I get this error.  So, I think wildfly can "see" the module, but something is awry.

```
23:24:15,889 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 33) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
    ("jdbc-driver" => "postgresql")
]) - failure description: "WFLYJCA0041: Failed to load module for driver [org.postgresql]"
```

Comment: Please check your logs, as far as I know there should be more detailed information (eg exception stacktraces) on why the module failed to load.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wildfly 10 Final postgres driver ClassCastException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36232968/wildfly-10-final-postgres-driver-classcastexception)

Comment: Note that `<datasource-class>org.postgresql.Driver</datasource-class>` is wrong: `org.postgresql.Driver` is not a `javax.sql.DataSource`; see the duplicate.

Comment: I wish that fixed it, it makes sense, but I get the same thing.  Again, I tried moving the dirver around, to no avail.  It is setup identically to the H2 driver that works...

Comment: Did you put the JAR and `module.xml` in `modules/org/postgresql` or `modules/org/postgresql/main`? It should be in the `main` directory.

Comment: I put it in the main directory.  I duplicate what was already done for the h2 driver (provided out of the box by wildfly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out I used "org.postgres" for the module name in standalone.xml instead of "org.postgresql" which is what I declared it as inside the module.xml

Answer (score 3):

**short answer**: put the driver in the `/wildfly/standalone/deployments` folder,  it will deploy the driver automatically

Comment: Works like a charm with Wildfly 21 and Postgres JDBC driver 42.x.

Comment: Thanks, I was searching so long for this. This and referencing the JDBC driver file name directly in <datasource><driver> of the standalone.xml fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this error and it was due to the module.xml not having the correct resource-root